# KiCAD - Automating library part creation

Tags: eaglecad, kicad, library, automation

I started a project in EAGLE, however found that the free version limits were too restricting. I then moved to KiCAD. I am trying to create a 144 pin chip as a library component for use in Eeschema.

In EAGLE I created commands from a spreadsheet using the datasheet so I could just copy and paste them into the command line. The commands designate the type of pin (power, I/O etc) pin name, pin number, position, orientation etc.

**Is there any way of automating the creation of a library in KiCAD?** I have spent a day or so going through the Eeschema manual but if the explanation is in there then I definitely missed it.

Comment: I am not familiar with the product but I suspect that your title should be "*Automatic library component creation*" or "*creating a component from a description file*".

Comment: Not yet. I have something for that in the pipeline (making the "pin table" dialog writeable, but it will be a few months until that's ready.

Comment: @SimonRichter Thanks. If you make that an answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's not an answer, because it doesn't solve the problem. For the time being, just creating components from a script is the sanest way.

Comment: It depends on whether you are talking about schematic symbols or PCB footprints. There is not currently an "official" way to automate symbol creation (this will likely change in v6). For footprints, there is the [kicad-footprint-generator](https://github.com/pointhi/kicad-footprint-generator) framework, which is implemented in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script is already out there, its called [KiPart](https://xesscorp.github.io/KiPart/docs/_build/singlehtml/index.html). It does what you need, create spreadsheet with all pins then run csv through the script and your part is generated.

Here is a nice video tutoiral from the author to follow along https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hX4l8i4TSWY

Comment: I wrote my own workbook in OpenOffice Calc in the end, but this would have been perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can just write out the library file directly from a script. It's a rather simple plain text format.

Comment: It looks like that's the new plan.